# Can we add a link to site-B inside Site-A so the link is only shown if users have access (atleast read) to site-B

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, navigation

We have a SharePoint online tenant. and we need to show and hide a link to a site based on users'permissions. for example:- Can we add a link to Site-B inside Site-A so the link is only shown if users have access (at-least read) to Site-B?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends how your users are given access.

If you are using Azure AD groups to control access (or you could also use an AzureAD group specifically for this purpose I guess), you can use [Audience Targeting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-content-to-a-specific-audience-on-a-sharepoint-site-68113d1b-be99-4d4c-a61c-73b087f48a81) with certain web parts.

Comment: Audience targeting i think will impact the search but have nothing to do with the permissions

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint navigation cannot be security trimmed. In other words, everybody sees the same navigation links regardless of their permissions.

There is no option to add a link to site-B inside Site-A so the link is only shown if users have access to site-B.